# Regarding student visa:-- What does it mean when visa officer asks ''What is the scope of your course''?

Tags: student-visa, interview

I have to attend a student-visa interview after a few days. I applied to a Master programme in Informatics Engineering.

What does it mean when visa officer asks the following question regarding the programme/course ?

> What is the scope of your Master course/programme?

Please reply asap. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No one is going to give you a pat answer that you can use for the appointment. If you did any research into the university programme before applying, you should have the information you need already. What topics does the programme cover? What courses?

Answer (score 3):

The scope of your course means what is covered by your course. You'd be expected to be able to answer regarding the topics/subjects that you will study, and probably talk about things like how it will be structured, assessed and the length of the course.

Answer (score 0):

Those are usually questions to assess your understanding of what you will be studying and to guarantee that you will succeed.

The scope of studies might mean: 
- What kind of studies do you want to carry?
- How much time will it take?
- Why choose this country in particular?
- What do you want to do after graduating? (to check if your career goals match)

You can also expect questions: 
- Regarding your previous studies (to see if it matches more or less your orientation).
- Regarding your awareness with what it takes financially, or if you master the language of the country you are going to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am talking about the scope of my course (Master in Informatics Engineering) .
--What is the meaning of ''scope'' here?
--Can u please give me a sample answer of ''what is the scope the course - master in informatics engineering?''

Comment: Hi, I guess that means a brief description of the master program you applied for. Anyways, you can prepare yourself generally for the types of questions I mentioned above and if this question exactly is asked you can ask this person to be more specific. Edit: Sorry I submitted my unfinished response accidentally.

Comment: I did NOT understand your answer....you said many things about scope...
Can u please tell me what does the word ''scope'' mean here exactly?

Comment: It's a standard English word - see any dictionary. "The extent of the area or subject matter that something deals with" (from https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scope). The point of the question is to find out if your course is "real" and that you know something about where it is being given (what university or college), how long it lasts, what you have already studied to be accepted for it, what qualifications you hope to get at the end of it, etc - i.e.that you really are going the attend, and it's not something you "just made up" because it would look good on your application.